# Nuke frame range with python script button

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nuke

thanks in advance for your help.

I have a set read nodes that need to be populated depending on the sequence and shot number. Correspondingly their frame range needs to be adjusted to the proper one. I have all this working, however I want to Nuke to change it's frame range according to the frame range I introduced in the dialog box .I've been trying with the code below in a script button but and I get an error that name 'Shot_Selector' is not defined. I've tried several things and can't make this work. I'm new to python, any help will be extremely appretiated.

```html
nuke.Root()['first_frame'].setValue(int({Shot_Selector.FStart}))
nuke.Root()['last_frame'].setValue(int({Shot_Selector.FEnd}))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like the `Shot_Selector` object is defined outside the scope of the code you've included. Could you [edit] the question to include a little bit more code to help us see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot_Selector was defined outside the funtion.